# Is it possible to create a MySQL partition and then create a subpartition by another column?

Tags: mysql, performance, partitioning

I read the docs about subpartitioning, but I think it doesn't cover what I'm trying to achieve.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-subpartitions.html

We have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `posts_countries` (
  `customer_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `partition_date` mediumint unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `post_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(6) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `impressions` int NOT NULL,
  `engagement` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customer_id`,`post_id`,`country`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

We have MILLON rows, performance is slow in every single query so we want to create PARTITION with MySQL. Some of the tests improved performance, because we always query by customer_id and by post_id.

What I want to achieve now is to make a PARTITION by customer_id, and then by partition_date. Partition date for example, stores 202207 as July 2022, and so on.

We want to create only 13 partitions by customer (he have very few customers). So, partition 1 would be:

```
Customer 1 -> VALUES LESS THAN MAX
Customer 1 -> VALUES LESS THAN 202207
Customer 1 -> VALUES LESS THAN 202206
...
Customer 1 -> VALUES LESS THAN 202107
...
...

Customer 2 -> VALUES LESS THAN MAX
Customer 2 -> VALUES LESS THAN 202207
Customer 2 -> VALUES LESS THAN 202206
...
Customer 2 -> VALUES LESS THAN 202107
```

I tried partitioning this way, but it's not partitioning by client_id

```
ALTER TABLE posts_countries
    PARTITION BY RANGE (partition_date)
SUBPARTITION BY HASH(customer_id)
SUBPARTITIONS 10
(
PARTITION 0c1 VALUES LESS THAN (202108) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION 0c2 VALUES LESS THAN (202109) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION 0c3 VALUES LESS THAN (202110) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION 0c4 VALUES LESS THAN (202111) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION 0c5 VALUES LESS THAN (202112) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION 0c6 VALUES LESS THAN (202201) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION 0c7 VALUES LESS THAN (202202) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION 0c8 VALUES LESS THAN (202203) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION 0c9 VALUES LESS THAN (202204) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION 0c10 VALUES LESS THAN (202205) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION 0c11 VALUES LESS THAN (202206) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION 0c12 VALUES LESS THAN (202207) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION 0c13 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE) ENGINE = InnoDB
);
```

Is this partitioning structure possible? Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing prevents.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test (id INT, grp INT, val INT)
>     PARTITION BY RANGE( grp )
>     SUBPARTITION BY HASH( val )
>     SUBPARTITIONS 2 (
>         PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (10),
>         PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
>     );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO test VALUES
> (1,1,1),
> (2,10,2),
> (3,20,3),
> (4,50,4),
> (5,80,5),
> (6,2000,6);
> ```

> ```
> SELECT TABLE_NAME,
>        PARTITION_NAME,
>        SUBPARTITION_NAME,
>        TABLE_ROWS
> FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS
> WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE();
> ```
>
> | TABLE_NAME | PARTITION_NAME | SUBPARTITION_NAME | TABLE_ROWS |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | test | p0 | p0sp0 | 0 |
> | test | p0 | p0sp1 | 1 |
> | test | p1 | p1sp0 | 3 |
> | test | p1 | p1sp1 | 2 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=02f48db3039e5968806161f91083055c)*

`SUBPARTITION BY KEY( val )` is available too.

Answer (score 0):

Partitioning is not a performance panacea.  Don't go through the effort of adding partitions until you check (ask me) whether it will speed up your queries.

The main cases where you *might* need partitioning:

- You will be purging old data and want to use `DROP PARTITION` instead of `DELETE`.
- The queries are "2-dimensional" with ranges in both -- as with latitude and longitude.

Show us your main queries.  It smells like they look something like

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ...
    WHERE customer_id = 4
      AND some_date BETWEEN ...
```

Well, this 'composite' index works perfectly well for a non-partitioned table:

```
INDEX(customer_id, some_date)
```

(That's not really 2-dimensional, since you will always(?) use `=` when testing `customer_id`.)

More discussion:  [*Partition*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint)